# Proposed delete tag: [start]

Tags: feature-request, tags, clean-up

The tag [start](/questions/tagged/start) is used very ambiguously, usually alongside a tag that provides the meaning that is ambiguously intended by [start](/questions/tagged/start).

It has no tag wiki, as no one appears to agree on a meaning. It only adds noise to the system, provides no useful grouping, and I can't imagine it's ever actually been used to help someone find content.

I'd like to recommend it be removed from the system.

Comment: Why not take care of `[end]` while we're at it?

Comment: @Mat: We have to `[start]` first, before we can `[end]`.

Comment: [end] tag appears to be juuust as ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that these two tags don't add much value, there are some questions tagged [end](/questions/tagged/end) which refer to [PHP's `end` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php), and I'm sure there are other frameworks/systems that have similar APIs.

However, these tags on their own can't support a question, so I've added them to the list of tags requiring cleanup in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012

So feel free to remove them, and update the main post with the progress as they're removed from the system.